# General questions about write ahead logs and recovery

Tags: recovery, cassandra, write-ahead-logging

I've recently learned about write ahead logs and failure recovery in the context of key-value stores like Cassandra and have some follow-up questions:

1. Do WALs get persisted into smaller snapshots so that we only need to recover from the latest snapshot instead of the entire commit history? What is the high-level mechanism for persisting and recovering from these snapshots?
2. Do logs get batched when writing to disk for performance? Is this at the risk of permanently losing data?
3. What happens when a machine fails during recovery from a WAL? Do we end up with partial results in the database? How do we recover from this state the next time the DB starts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! A friendly reminder that you should only ask one question at a time. Each post has to be focused on a single specific question so it is clear what is being asked. For guidance, see https://stackexchange.com/tour and https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an application issues a write request:

- the data is stored in a memory structure called `memtable`, and
- persisted to disk by appending the mutation to a `commitlog` (WAL).

Appending to the `commitlog` is done for two reasons:

1. In the event of a server outage or hardware failure, the mutations can be replayed the next time the node is restarted.
2. This makes writes very fast in Cassandra since all that is required is to continuously append mutations to the end of the log without having to perform disk seeks to write the updates to a data file.

The data in the memtables will eventually get flushed to a data file on disk called SSTable (sorted-string table file). The memtable flush is triggered when:

- the memtable exceeds the allocated space in memory,
- the commitlog exceeds the maximum commitlog space on disk,
- the data exceeds the memtable cleanup threshold (only applies to earlier versions of Cassandra), or
- an operator initiates a table flush manually.

Once a memtable is flushed to disk, the data in its corresponding commitlog is purged.

Since the mutations are persisted to disk, they are durable and will survive restarts and unplanned outages. In the worst case scenario where the commitlog disk/volume is lost, the data isn't lost forever because the mutations are sent to all replicas in the cluster so copies exist that can be synced to other replicas through repairs.

For more info, see [How data is written in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataWritten.html). Cheers!